# Implement factory design pattern with spring annotaion

Tags: spring, annotations, design-patterns, factory

I have a factory class that should return me an instance of `classA` or `classB`. These classes implement interface `XYZ`:

```
   interface xyz;
   getInstance()

   @service 
   classA implements xyz{
      public void checkStatus(){
      }
   }

   @service  classB implements xyz{
      public void checkStatus(){
      }
   }
```

Factory class:

```
   @component
   class ABCFactory{
       @Autowire classA A;
       public static getInstance(str a){
           return classA;
       }
   }
```

Client code:

```
   Class A a = ABCFactory.getInstance("A");
   a.checkStatus();
```

I get null pointer exception -- probably `a` is returned as null?

What is the best approach to implement the factory pattern with spring annotation and autowired bean?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say with any certainty why your auto-wiring isn't taking place without seeing your Spring config. My first guess is that you don't have component scanning switched on:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

Adding something like that to your spring config file (with the correct package) will tell Spring to scan the package structure for fields that need to be auto-wired, and services that can be used for auto-wiring.

Comment: I cannot call ABCFactory.getInstance("A"); because getInstance is not static so how should I call getInstance from client. Configuration is correct as you mentioned

Comment: I found the solution, just configure factory class in client controller which successfully completed the chain and called the service

Answer (score 0):

`static` is the root of all evil. How did you managed to access `classA` here?

```
@Component
class ABCFactory{
   @Autowire classA A;
   public static getInstance(str a){
       return classA;
   }
}
```

`A` field is not static while `getInstance()` method is - your code won't compile.

Furthermore, dependency injection works on instances, not on `static` classes. Thus you should get rid of `static`:

```
@Component
class ABCFactory {
   @Autowire classA A;
   public xyz getInstance(str a){
       return A;
   }
}
```

and inject `ABCFactory` where you need it (e.g. in other services or controllers):

```
@Autowired
private ABCFactory factory;
```

BTW your design looks supicious in Spring environment, what do you want to achieve?